# in-sample forecast plot with test_forecast in app

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, arima, forecast

I split a time series into train set and test set, then fit the train set with ARIMA model and forecast the test set. The codes work well in R and have no plot output in shiny.
The code of app is as follows,

```
library(shiny)
library(TSstudio)
library(forecast)
library(plotly)
# Define UI for application that draws a plot
ui <- fluidPage(
   plotOutput("out")
  
)
# in-sample forecast and draws a plot
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$out <- renderPlot({
      USgas_split <- ts_split(USgas, sample.out = 12)
      train <- USgas_split$train
      test <- USgas_split$test
      md1 <- auto.arima(train)
      fc1 <- forecast(md1, h = 12)
      test_forecast(forecast.obj = fc1, actual = USgas, test = test) 
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: i have solved the problem with plotlyOutput and renderPlotly

Comment: This is not a question or a problem, at least not as it is currently stated.